# Why do I need sun-jaxws.xml file on glassfish 4?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jax-ws

I am making some first steps into the world of JAX-WS and use glassfish 4.

I just tried to rebuild the JavaEE7 Oracle Jax-WS examples and have the following webservice:

```
@WebService
public class Hello {

    @WebMethod
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        System.out.println("Webservice sayHello called...");
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

There is nothing more.. I have deployed it on glassfish, I can use the Tester, I can see the WSDL - fine.

Now I was writing the client that should be called by a JSF2 view.. Here comes the bean:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class HelloServiceClient {

    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation="http://localhost:8080/HelloService/HelloService?WSDL")
    private HelloService service;

    public String callHello() {
        Hello helloPort = service.getHelloPort();
        return helloPort.sayHello(" JSF2 View!");
    }

    public String callWSSayHello(String name) {
        Hello helloPort = service.getHelloPort();
        return helloPort.sayHello(name);
    }
}
```

There is also a minimalistic view just calling the callHello() method and display the result.

I was deploying that application to the same glassfish server and got the following error:

> java.io.IOException:
>   com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred
>   during deployment: Exception while loading the app :
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11:
>   Laufzeitdeskriptor konnte nicht geparst werden:
>   javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Laufzeitdeskriptor
>   "/WEB-INF/sun-jaxws.xml" fehlt. Please see server.log for more
>   details.

So I do not understand that concept of sun-jaxws - and even though - the oracle docs and example don't tell me anything about it.

Did I do something wrong - maybe in my IDE or anything else?

Comment: As a default is your glassfish server tested and running normally? (remote side)

Comment: It is a fresh local installation and I did not configure anything on glassfish itself.
I can see the deployed WebService and use the built-in Tester successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer for my problem:

My IDE automatically added the WSServlet as a listener to my web.xml -> if you remove that from the web.xml it is working as expected.